# How can I populate items in a cart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

I am currently trying to build out an ecommerce site and have run into some issues. The main one is that I can get the current items that will be sold to sell but when I add them to the cart and it get's saved to state so that the user doesn't loose their items and that is being shown to the customer through a badge.  I am stuck with how to populate the selected items in a cart.

I am now properly saving the items  to storage and can get the cart page to populate in a modual but I am unable to see the items themselves only the quantity.

Below is the page where I am using to sho the store

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import products from './product'
import CheckOutModal from './CheckOutModal'
import { CartContext } from '../context/cart'
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';


export default function CheckOutCart({}) {
  const { cartItems, addToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart, getCartTotal } = useContext(CartContext)

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex-col flex items-center bg-white gap-8 p-10 text-black text-sm">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Cart</h1>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
          {cartItems.map((item) => (
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center" key={item.id}>
              <div className="flex gap-4">
                <img src={item.thumbnail} alt={item.title} className="rounded-md h-24" />
                <div className="flex flex-col">
                  <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">{item.title}</h1>
                  <p className="text-gray-600">{item.price}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex gap-4">
                <button
                  className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 text-white text-xs font-bold uppercase rounded hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700"
                  onClick={() => {
                    addToCart(item)
                  }}
                >+
                </button>
                <p>{item.quantity}</p>
                <button
                  className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 text-white text-xs font-bold uppercase rounded hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700"
                  onClick={() => {
                    removeFromCart(item)
                  }}
                > -
                </button>

              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        {
          cartItems.length > 0 ? (
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-between items-center">
              <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">Total: ${getCartTotal()}</h1>
              <button
                className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 text-white text-xs font-bold uppercase rounded hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700"
                onClick={() => {
                  clearCart()
                }}
              >
                Clear cart
              </button>

            </div>
          ) : (
            <>
              <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">Your cart is empty</h1>
            </>
          )
        }
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
        <CheckOutModal  cartItems.length > 0  />

   

      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

and here is the modal where I want the cart to show up in

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { CartContext } from '../context/cart'
const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  border: '2px solid #000',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};
export default function BasicModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  const { cartItems, addToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart, getCartTotal } = useContext(CartContext)

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}   >

        ({cartItems.length})
        Check Out</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <>
            <div className="flex-col flex items-center bg-white gap-8 p-10 text-black text-sm">
              <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Cart</h1>
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
                {cartItems.map((item) => (
                  <div className="flex justify-between items-center" key={item.id}>
                    <div className="flex gap-4">
                      <img src={item.thumbnail} alt={item.title} className="rounded-md h-24" />
                      <div className="flex flex-col">
                        <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">{item.title}</h1>
                        <p className="text-gray-600">{item.price}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex gap-4">
                      <button
                        className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 text-white text-xs font-bold uppercase rounded hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700"
                        onClick={() => {
                          addToCart(item)
                        }}
                      >
                        +
                      </button>
                      <p>{item.quantity}</p>
                      <button
                        className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 text-white text-xs font-bold uppercase rounded hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700"
                        onClick={() => {
                          removeFromCart(item)
                        }}
                      >
                        -
                      </button>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
              {
                cartItems.length > 0 ? (
                  <div className="flex flex-col justify-between items-center">
                    <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">Total: ${getCartTotal()}</h1>
                    <button
                      className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 text-white text-xs font-bold uppercase rounded hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700"
                      onClick={() => {
                        clearCart()
                      }}
                    >
                      Clear cart
                    </button>

                  </div>

                ) : (
                  <>
                    <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">Your cart is empty</h1>

                  </>
                )
              }
            </div>
          </>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is the context  file

```
import React from "react";
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import products from "../components/product";

export const CartContext = createContext()

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : [])

  const addToCart = (item) => {
    const isItemInCart = cartItems.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id);

    if (isItemInCart) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
          cartItem.id === item.id
            ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
            : cartItem
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...item, quantity: 1 }]);
    }
  };

  const removeFromCart = (item) => {
    const isItemInCart = cartItems.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id);

    if (isItemInCart.quantity === 1) {
      setCartItems(cartItems.filter((cartItem) => cartItem.id !== item.id));
    } else {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
          cartItem.id === item.id
            ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity - 1 }
            : cartItem
        )
      );
    }
  };

  const clearCart = () => {
    setCartItems([]);
  };

  const getCartTotal = () => {
    return cartItems.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
  }, [cartItems]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cartItems = localStorage.getItem("cartItems");
    if (cartItems) {
      setCartItems(JSON.parse(cartItems));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        cartItems,
        addToCart,
        removeFromCart,
        clearCart,
        getCartTotal,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Here is the page where the store shows up, this part works fine but I can't poplate the selected items.

```
import React from "react";
import RemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Remove';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Badge from '@mui/material/Badge';
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import  stockmug from '../images/stockmug.jpg'
import ShoppingCartWidgit from './ShoppingCart'
import products  from "./product";
import ShoppingCartCheckoutIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCartCheckout';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
import { CartContext } from '../context/cart'
import Cart from './CheckOutCart'

import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  CardContent,Button,
  Typography,
  CardHeader,CardMedia,
} from "@material-ui/core/";
import tinkerbell from '../images/tinkerbell.jpg'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  cards: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));







export default  function AltCard() {
 

  const { cartItems, addToCart, removeFromCart } = useContext(CartContext)







    // getting stored value
    
  const classes = useStyles();
   

// ],   
// id for prouctremove
  

 
//  cart added here



  return (

    <>
      
        
        
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Grid
              container
              spacing={2}
              direction="row"
              justify="flex-start"
              alignItems="flex-start"
          >
              {/* <Grid item xs={12}> */}
              {products.map((elem) => (
                  <Grid
                      item
                      xs={6} sm={4}
                      className={classes.cards}
                      key={products.indexOf(elem)}
                  >
                      <Card>
                          <CardHeader
                              title={` ${elem.Title}`}
                              subheader={`price: $  ${elem.price}`} />
                          <CardMedia
                              component="img"
                              alt="a litter of puppies inside their doggie bed"
                              height="140"

                              image={` ${elem.imageId}`} />

                          <CardContent>
                              <Typography  
                              description={` ${elem.description}`}
 variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                  <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                                      <Button 
                                        
                                      
                                      
                                      onClick={() => {
                                        addToCart(products)}}

                                          size="large" variant="contained" endIcon={<AddIcon />}>
                                          Add To  Cart
                                      </Button>
                                      <Button
                                        // disabled={shouldDisabled}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                          removeFromCart(products)}}
  
                                      id="RemoveFromCart" 
                                       size="large" variant="contained" endIcon={<RemoveIcon />}>
                                          Remove From  Cart
                                      </Button>
                                      
                                  </Stack>
                              </Typography>
                          </CardContent>
                      </Card>
                  </Grid>
              ))}
              {/* </Grid> */}
          </Grid>
     

  

  
      </div>

      <Badge badgeContent={0} 
        // invisible={invisible} 
      // aria-label={notificationsLabel(ItemsinCart)}
      
      color="primary">
              <ShoppingCartCheckoutIcon  size="large"color="action" />
          </Badge></>


  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that I noticed

1. You can use a function as an initial value but the default return value should be `0` not `""` and make sure your initial value from localStorage is`number` not `string`. You probably need to use `parseInt`. And I don't think it's a good idea to use localStorage for your case. Consider using some state management libraries such as `recoil` or `Redux`.
2. When you just want to increase the value use prev value, not state value. For example, do like this

```js
onClick={() => {
    // increase the amount of the counter by one and add to local storage
    setItemCount((count) => count + 1);
}}
```

3. Delete `onChange` method and `value` from your Button it is doing nothing. If you need to show the count then show it somewhere else not on the button.
4. I'm not sure what `functionToExecute` does. If you want to prevent negative value. You can use your state

```js
...
const shouldDisabled = itemCount < 1
...

<Button
  id="RemoveFromCart"
  onClick={() => {
    setItemCount((count) => count - 1);
  }}
  size="large"
  variant="contained"
  endIcon={<RemoveIcon />}
  disabled={shouldDisabled}
>
  Remove From Cart
</Button>
```

Hope this can help you! You can find more information about React state management here > https://react.dev/learn/managing-state

Comment: That helps with the minus issue, do you have any recommendations on how to show the selected items that get added to the cart?

Comment: The checkout page code is poorly formatted I think I can help you if you format your code.

Comment: I have updated the page with the context and the modal which is where I am having the issue, I am unable to get the new array to populate in the modal.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, thanks.